# SQLBase union doesn't work with alias. Why?

Tags: sql, guptateamdeveloper, sqlbase, centura

I am trying to execute a SQL query using UNION in my SQLBase database. Also I want to use an alias for the column. But it doesn't work with the alias.

I've never used UNION but I always use alias.

It works:

```
SELECT color
FROM my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT color
FROM my_table;
```

It doesn't works:

```
SELECT color AS my_color
FROM my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT color AS my_color
FROM my_table;
```

The error is:

```
09814 PRS RCT Result column name can be only be specified with top select statement.
```

I have the **SQLBase Language Reference (SQLBase 11.7)** book but it doesn't have an answer.

Comment: What a strange error -- but just remove the `as my_color` from the second query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I know you can specify alias columnnames only in the first part of a union.
This one should work:

```
SELECT color AS my_color
FROM my_table
UNION ALL
SELECT color
FROM my_table;
```